# laravel redirecting users who are not logged in

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am developing a project with Laravel. I have created two files for the admin panel, namely route and AdminController. Additionally, I have created a dashboard. When a user tries to access /admin/dashboard without logging in, I want to redirect them to /admin, but I couldn't succeed, and I'm getting the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [login] not defined.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/dashboard
```

When a user logs in, the redirection works correctly. How can I overcome this issue?

routes > web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\SliderController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Route::get('/', function () {
    $sliders = App\Models\Slider::all();
    $projects = App\Models\Project::all();
    return view('homepage', compact('sliders', 'projects'));
});

Route::get('/projects', [ProjectController::class, 'index'])->name('projects.index');
Route::get('/projects/{slug}', [ProjectController::class, 'show'])->name('projects.show');

// Admin login route
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/admin', [AdminController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/admin', [AdminController::class, 'login'])->name('admin.login.submit');
});

// Admin routes (protected with auth middleware)
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('/admin/logout', [AdminController::class, 'logout'])->name('admin.logout');
});

// Catch-all route to redirect unauthorized access to login page
Route::get('/admin/{any}', function () {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        // Kullanıcı giriş yapmışsa, admin paneline yönlendir.
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
    } else {
        // Kullanıcı giriş yapmamışsa, login sayfasına yönlendir.
        return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }
})->where('any', '.*');
```

app > http > controllers > AdminController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Giriş başarılı, yönetim paneline yönlendir
            return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
        } else {
            // Giriş başarısız, hata mesajıyla birlikte giriş sayfasına yönlendir
            return redirect()->route('admin.login')->with('error', 'Giriş başarısız!');
        }
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }
}
```

Comment: Php artisan route:list and check if exist "admin.login" in the list of routes.

Comment: I checked, yes there is.

"GET|HEAD | Closure  | web | GET|HEAD | admin | admin.login | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@showLoginForm | web"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception already gives you enough information to tell you what you are missing:

```
Route [login] not defined
```

In the web routes that you have provided, there isn't a route with the name `login`, the route that the default Auth will throw your unauthenticated user to.

Instead of using `Auth::check` directly on your routes, you can instead use your own [custom middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) and register it on the `Kernel`

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I created a new middleware and implemented redirection for "admin.login" within it. Then, I edited the route file, and the issue was resolved.

ps: php artisan make:middleware RedirectIfNotAuthenticated

Comment: glad it helps! yes, you can do it that way, but i would prefer to give some prefix to the file name so you won't be confused in the future, imo